# Parse: Object type for upload image

Tags: parse-platform

I need to upload an image from my android application to parse data browser.
And I have created a class - "Class A", that has "ABC" column with File type.
But I kept on getting the following error whenever I upload image into "ABC".

```
can't add objects for a field that isn't an array
```

I google-ed awhile, and found this [link](https://www.parse.com/questions/problem-while-adding-object).
So, I try to upload the image to a new class and column (I did not create this first. I let the Parse automatically create and assign it for me upon I uploaded my image to it).
Then I noticed that, the column type being assigned to the uploaded image is an array.
Would be great if someone can actually explain this further?

Here is the code: -- EDIT --

```
ParseObject reportObject = new ParseObject(ParseClass.CaseImageClass);
reportObject.add(ParseClass.FObjectKeyAttr, objectId);

ParseFile parseBitmapFile = new ParseFile(uqID.toString() + ".png", byteArray);
parseBitmapFile.save();
reportObject.add(ParseClass.ImageAttr, parseBitmapFile);
reportObject.saveInBackground();
```

Answer (score 0):

When you upload an image to parse, the image Class must be a PFFile class. Without seeing the code and setup of your database, it's hard to determine why you're receiving this error. As long as the property/hash/value associated with your Parse class is referencing a PFFile and all of the property/hash/value types match up with each column and the column's respective name, you should be fine. Something in this case just doesn't match up causing the error you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
parseBitmapFile.save();
```

you should use saveInBackground() in place of .save();

```
 ParseObject.registerSubclass(Imaggg.class);
        ParseObject testObject = ParseObject.create("MyProfiles");
      ParseFile file = new ParseFile("123.png",imagearray);
      file.saveInBackground();

     testObject.put("comments",str_comment);
        testObject.put("imageFile",file);
        testObject.put("userName",user_name);


       testObject.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {

            @Override
            public void done(ParseException e) {

                  dlg.dismiss();
                  Log.e("Exception", "get: " +e);
                  if (e == null) {
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Shared Succesfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    } else {
                      // Sign up didn't succeed. Look at the ParseException
                      // to figure out what went wrong
                         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Something went wrong.Please try again later",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }


            }
        });
```

Here imagearray  is the byte[] .

Answer (score 0):

Im guessing this line of code is to set the object id? Parse sets their own object id by default. If you are overriding it then there is a separate command to be used for accessing the objectID column defined by Parse.

> reportObject.add(ParseClass.FObjectKeyAttr, objectId);

Add is used only if the column type is an array. Try changing this to IF you are NOT overriding the default objectID column and making your own instead.

> reportObject.put(ParseClass.FObjectKeyAttr, objectId);

This line of code tells parse to make the column as an array. if you want to change it to a ParseFile type or any other type then change the .add to .put as written in the above code. .add, .addAll. addAllUnique are reserved only for array type columns.

> reportObject.add(ParseClass.ImageAttr, parseBitmapFile);
>   reportObject.put(ParseClass.ImageAttr, parseBitmapFile);

Let me know if you face any other problems. Im happy to help.